# What is the best way for sharing common functionality or reusing existing code in micro-service architecture?

Tags: architecture, microservices, architectural-patterns, communication

I just curious to know that what is the best practice or way for sharing common functionality or code among the micro-services. For example, there is one micro-service which is responsible for the operations related to `user` entity. Now if `X` micro-service needs some data related to `user` entity, then how can this be achieved? Coding some logic related to `user` in `X` is not an good idea, as it will create redundancy.

What I know so far is,

1. We can use facade design pattern, in which we can pack common functionalities in some library (kind of JAR) and share this among different micro-services, but then it will create constraint on technology which can be used for micro-services. For example, JAR can mostly be used with Java projects.
2. We can use some queuing system, to send messages from one micro-service to another. But I am not sure exactly how can we achieve this and how much is this reliable and compatible.
3. We can directly use HTTP REST calls between micro-services for communication. But again this will add latency in response time, which is bad.

So which is the best way for micro-service internal communication?

Comment: Look back at the rationale (pros/cons) for choosing micro-services for the project to begin with as well as the particular micro-service architecture/scope split chosen for the project. If the question still stands unanswered it *might* indicate that those may need re-visiting.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this discussion with a coworker recently - it's the nature of microservices to have functionality available as REST services (no longer in-process). If that's not practical, don' put it in a microservice (or change the API).

Let's say you have AddUserToGroup() and IsUserInGroup(). The former probably happens relatively rarely and the cost of the operation is orders of magnitude larger than the cost of a network call. Also, you probably want to microservice that, so you can change account providers later. Whereas IsUserInGroup() probably gets called all the time and the implementation is trivial. You'd have to refactor and GetUserGroups() once at logon. (contrived example, use OAuth :) )